# Is there a conformal map between euclidean and nil geometry?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, nil-geometry

I'm looking for a conformal map (not necessarily injective or surjective) from ordinary 3-dimensional euclidean space (or a region of it) to some example of nil geometry; I would be most interested if the nil space in question was compact.

So, my question is:

For some riemannian nilmanifold $N$, does a conformal map from some $A \subseteq E^3$ to $N$ always exist, or does it never exist, or is its existence dependent on other properties?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - is there a natural Riemannian metric on a nilmanifold?

Comment: @user8268 the wikipedia page for nilmanifolds does mention "compact riemannian manifolds" so I'm guessing those exist

Comment: since your $N$ is a nilpotent Lie group $G$ modulo a discrete subgroup, and since local conformal transformations of $E^3$ are $SO(4,1)$, you would see the nilpotent Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ as a Lie subalgebra of $so(4,1)$. I _think_ that all the nilpotent Lie subalgebras of $so(4,1)$ are abelian, which would imply that $N$ is a torus, but I didn't check that.

Comment: You have to specify a Riemannian metric on your nil-manifold. The standard choice is to project a left-invariant Riemannian metric from the real Heisenberg group. Such a metric is nowhere conformally-flat, hence, there cannot be  a conformal map you are asking about.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I may be missing something, but given that that's the *standard* choice, is it possible that a conformally flat metric could exist? Or does something forbid this?
Would you mind pointing me towards books or other resources I could look into to learn about this?

Comment: For instance, there is an old theorem of Goldman that Nil manifolds admit no conformally flat metrics.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks, I'll be looking into that! It's exactly the sort of answer I'd been looking for.